# Foreign Key Constraints Errors

Tags: mysql

I keep getting a ERROR1215 when I create my table. I have narrowed the problem down to two attributes "score" and "criteriaNum". I cannot figure out why its causing problems though.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sys`.`rubric` (
  `programName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `criteriaNum` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `score` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `criteria` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  `description` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`programName`, `criteriaNum`,`score`),
  CONSTRAINT `rubric_programName`
    FOREIGN KEY (`programName`)
    REFERENCES `sys`.`degree_program` (`programName`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    COMMENT 'Each entry in the rubric table corresponds to a criteria,score pair.';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`sys`.`evaluator_scores` (
  `evaluatorName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `aid` INT NOT NULL,
  `programName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `criteriaNum` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `score` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`, `evaluatorName`, `programName`, `criteriaNum`, `score`),
  CONSTRAINT `score_aid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`aid`)
    REFERENCES `sys`.`application` (`aid`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `score_evalName`
    FOREIGN KEY (`evaluatorName`)
    REFERENCES `sys`.`evaluations` (`evaluatorName`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `score_programName`
    FOREIGN KEY (`programName`)
    REFERENCES `sys`.`rubric` (`programName`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `score_criteriaNum`
    FOREIGN KEY (`criteriaNum`)
    REFERENCES `sys`.`rubric` (`criteriaNum`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `score_score`
    FOREIGN KEY (`score`)
    REFERENCES `sys`.`rubric` (`score`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

If I remove the score and criteriaNum constraints, it builds evaluator_scores. Otherwise though I get errors. Can anyone find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of foreign keys is that the parent table must have a corresponding record in order to include that key in the child. In your parent table, the primary key is (programName, criteriaNum, score). Yet in your child table, you are trying to create three foreign key constraints to the rubric table, one for each individual column.

If you combine those three constraints into one and match the primary key columns, it ought to work.